# What happens to the reputation/upvotes after serial upvotes?

Tags: discussion, serial-voting

Today I faced this kind of situation. Suddenly I get repeated up votes from a particular user (4 up votes) and today I reached the reputation limit of 200.

Assume if those votes are reversed, would I be gaining the up votes/reputation I got after reaching 200?

[image]

Is there not a mechanism to report this kind of serial upvotes?

Comment: > Whenever serial voting gets reversed, all days involved in the serial voting will be recalculated as if the serial votes had never happened, and any reputation you might have lost due to those serial votes hitting the reputation cap will be given to you at that time. Serial voters will not prevent you from gaining reputation that you deserve.

Comment: guys this is not a duplicate question, this question is different. and the answer provided are wrong! for me the reputations were not given as you explained.